# Algorithm to convert STL files to STEP files

Tags: computational-geometry

My goal is to learn the algorithms that allow to convert STL files to STEP files.

I am struggling to find learning materials.

Can you suggest here research papers, books, open source code about this topic, please? So I am not just interested in converting the STL to STEP file, but in understanding *how* to perform the conversion.

Comment: Did you check the standards? [STL](http://www.fabbers.com/tech/STL_Format) and [STEP](https://webstore.ansi.org/Standards/ISO/ISO10303212016)

Comment: Seeing that STEP is a proprietary standard, I suspect that no one has written a document which you can access to for free. That would potentially violate rights of the copyright holder as most standards documents are intended for use by ONE user. As a result, writing and releasing a document would invite a cease-and-desist order and even a lawsuit. Most standards have academic licensing schemes or are accessible through university libraries for educational purposes. That may be your only option. That being said FreeCAD can translate from STL to STEP, but you would have to read their codebase.

Comment: Even if you have all the details of the format available, e.g., BREP from OpenCascade, the conversion is not trivial and will need several algorithms from, e.g., https://geometry-central.net/, to produce acceptable results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The central concept here is the conversion from polygonal meshes (such as .stl) to boundary representations (as in STEP files).

It is not a trivial conversion. Here's [an article by Andrey Tumanin](https://habr.com/en/post/465237/) that should help.

I believe he's written more on the topic, but was unable to find the papers.